# Why all of Template10 (Services) does not exist in Template10 (Library)?

Tags: win-universal-app, template10

I installed template10 from Nuget, and although I downloaded template10 through this link:
https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10

it has Template10 (Installer), Template10 (Library), Template10 (Services), Template10 (Validation),... . just Template10 (Library) exists in Nuget, why others are not in Nuget and how can I use them? I just should copy past what I need?

Comment: This is two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explained in this issue: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/616

> Services is not tested and should be labeled as EXPERIMENTAL. They originated from my own library of services from Windows 8 development and are part of this so the code can be used, but I have not adequately tested it to be comfortable including it in the library at this time. I hope that makes sense.

"The Library is the only project that comprises the Nuget package."

You should add the other projects via Git Clone, for example, if you want to use them in your app.